# Regular expression to match 'hashtagged' words not matching the first one in string

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regular expression to try to match all 'hashtagged' words in a given string:

```
/([^a-zA-Z0-9-_&])#([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/
```

In the following string, `#rather`, `#pointless` and `#text` will be successfully matched:

**My string:** `this is some #rather #pointless meaningless #text.`

However, in a string where the very first word is hashtagged, only the subsequent hashtagged words (`#pointless` and `#text`) are matched:

**My string:** `#rather #pointless meaningless #text`

How can I ensure the very first word of my string is also matched if it is hashtagged?

**EDIT:**

I'm using the expression in my PHP script, or more specifically, inside a `preg_replace()` function like so:

```
$content = preg_replace( '/#\w+/g', "$1<a href=\"/tags/$2\" title=\"$2\">#$2</a>", $content );
```

Comment: did you write that on your own or you got it from someone else?

Comment: The expression was taken from [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-automatically-link-twitter-usernames-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part (between the parenthesis) requires some text to be in front of the hash.
You can make it optional if it is at the beginning of the string:

```
/(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9-_&])#([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/
```

As some suggested, you can avoid writing all matching characters explicitly (using groups):

```
/(^|[^\w-&])#(\w+)/
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to use the \w character class. Not sure what language you're writing in, but you can do this very simply like this:

```
/(\w*)#(\w+)/
```

Edit: Changed the above to make capturing groups fitting with your replacement string.

Comment: When I use this, it results in `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'`. My code is: `$content = preg_replace( '/#\w+/g', "$1<a href=\"/tags/$2\" title=\"$2\">#$2</a>", $content );`

Comment: That looks like php syntax. I'm not used to that. The g is a global modifier. But I see that you want to make some sort of replacement directly, not retrieve the matches and loop through them, which was my assumption. Could you update your question and include the replacement string and the expected result so that I can update my answer?

Comment: I've already accepted an answer but +1 for the updated answer, works great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Does your language/engine support negative lookbehinds?

`(?<![\w-&])#(\w+)`

http://www.regexr.com/39alk

Comment: what is a negative lookbehind? and what are you using it for?

Comment: @pqnet OP checks if there is char/dash/ampersand in front of a hashtag

Comment: @pqnet A negative lookbehind is an advanced regex feature which is not part of all implementations. It's used to place a group-is-preceded by requirement, and really shouldn't be necessary in this scenario.

Comment: @Mithon well, if you know your stuff and your language supports it why not? Of course I wouldn't recommend this to someone who's still learning basic regex though, but I'm happy to learn new stuff

Comment: @pqnet Because in all programming matters, KISS rules. And this is hitting a very small nail with a very large hammer. Furthermore, lookarounds are less performant due to added complexity. I realize it might be negligible here, but I always try to use the simplest and most readable way. Especially when advicing a novice, which appears to be the case here. (regex novice, at least.)

Comment: I'm definitely a novice when it comes to regex. Thanks for your help, and comments. Been helpful!